# How to turn on evil mode on emacs startup

Tags: plugins, emacs

I've been using nvim for a while and recently thought about checking emacs out after learning about evil mode. I made `init.el` in `.config/emacs`, installed evil mode and figured i would try to enable it whenever i start up emacs.

So i wrote this bit of code in `init.el`:

```
(defun evil-mode-on ()
  (require evil)
  (evil-mode 1))

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'evil-mode-on)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be missing apostrophe(') in `require`. It should be `(require 'evil)`

Enabling evil mode at startup could be as simple as specifying

```
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

in your `init.el` file as long as package is already installed and/loaded.

[Github](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) page has in detailed instruction to install it automatically with the help of `use-package`.